# Grep specific string in mixed file on linux

Tags: sed, awk, tr

How to extract only the string **q9I9YP1V013809** from this output:

```
q9I9YP1V013809     1472 Thu Oct 18 11:34  test@test.com 
                                          test1@test.com 
                                          test2@test.com 
                                          test3@test.com
```

Expected View:

```
q9I9YP1V013809
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do:

```
awk 'NF>1{print $1}' file
```

since OP didn't mention any rule of the expected string. it could have '@' too.

test:

```
kent$  echo "q9I9YP1V013809     1472 Thu Oct 18 11:34  test@test.com 
                                          test1@test.com 
                                          test2@test.com 
                                          test3@test.com"|awk 'NF>1{print $1}'
q9I9YP1V013809
```

Answer (score 2):

One of many ways. If first field doesn't contain an `@`, print it.

```
awk '$1 !~ /@/ { print $1; }' infile
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check presence of `@` character or base it on # of fields present as in this command:

```
awk 'NF > 5 { print $1 }' input.file
```

Answer (score 0):

To skip all lines that start with a space, and remove everything after a space for the remaining files, do

```
grep -v '^ ' file.in | sed "s/ .*//"
```

Compared to awk, you need to start two processes, *but* it is much clearer what is being done.

Another solution, `sed` only:

```
sed "/^ /d;s/ .*//" file.in
```

Not as clear, but only one process. First `sed` command (`/^ /d`) deletes all lines that start with a space; second command is the same as above.

Comment: Why is awk not clear? Personally I think it is the other way around, as in `sed` and `grep` you need to remember all the flags, while `awk` can be done with simple and universal operators.

Comment: Yes but when I have multiple entries similar to that I get to many new lines simple output after sed:

<pre>q9I6OEFg003411

q9IBZWhC012017

q9IBZRsb011962</pre>

Comment: @Bernhard: well, everyone has a favorite. I particularly don't like awk, although I have been using it intensely before I learned perl.

Comment: @KalinBorisov: so, where is the problem? I thought that this was the intention?

Comment: Let me explain when I have from right side many e-mail your code make empty spaces about of that how many mails are on that specific string

Comment: Um, no, not really. Unless you have tabs, and not spaces.

Answer (score 0):

If it's always the first word, and other lines are prefixed with whitespace use:

```
<infile grep -Eo '^[^[:blank:]]+'
```